# C# generic methods, type parameters in new() constructor constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-constraints

Is there a way to create a Generic Method that uses the `new()` constraint to require classes with constructor attributes of specific types?

**For Example:**

I have the following code:

```
public T MyGenericMethod<T>(MyClass c) where T : class
{
    if (typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(MyClass) }) == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid class supplied");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to have something like this instead?

```
public T MyGenericMethod<T>(MyClass c) where T : new(MyClass)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

**EDIT:** There's [a suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2122427-expand-generic-constraints-for-constructors) regarding this. Please vote so we can have this feature in C#!

**EDIT 2:** The site has been taken down. Now the suggestion is on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/769). Follow up there!

Comment: I'm a little confused. What exactly are you trying to accomplish. Will the constructor take a parameter of MyClass, or are you limiting T to MyClass?

Comment: User voice has long since gone the way of the dodo, but there is still [an issue for this in the csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/769) repository. Here's to the next decade!

Comment: Great! Updated the question with the new URL. Hope this feature is added in the next 10 years, haha.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not really; C# only supports no-args constructor constraints.

The workaround I use for generic arg constructors is to specify the constructor as a delegate:

```
public T MyGenericMethod<T>(MyClass c, Func<MyClass, T> ctor) {
    // ...
    T newTObj = ctor(c);
    // ...
}
```

then when calling:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
MyGenericMethod<OtherClass>(c, co => new OtherClass(co));
```

Comment: You can even only use `Func<T> ctor` as a delegate and then pass `MyClass` only in that delegate. This way, `MyGenericMethod` can work with different constructors, e.g. when different dependencies are involved.

Answer (score 9):

No.  Unfortunately, generic constraints only allow you to include:

```
where T : new()
```

Which specifies that there is a default, parameterless constructor.  There is no way to constrain to a type with a constructor which accepts a specific parameter type.

For details, see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I read that article, but it was not very specific about the new() constraint.

Thanks anyway, I guess I'll leave my validation right where it is...

Comment: @Joel: The option they show is the ONLY option for the new() constraint.  THere's no way to add parameters.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible in C# to constrain the generic type to have a constructor of a specific signature. Only the parameterless constructor is supported by new().

Comment: It would be a nice addition though!